# Terraform: An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

guys. I am studying Terraform and successfully implemented it on AWS with some simple codes.
But when I run a little bit of complex code as I created, I get an error like the one below:

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 7, in data "aws_subnets" "default":
│   7:   vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
│
│ An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here.
```

I have no idea what was wrong, could you guys please take a look and give me some advice?

#================================================================

Here is my code:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "*****************"
  secret_key = "**********************************"
  region     = "ap-northeast-2"
}

data "aws_vpc" "default" {            
  default = true                   
}

data "aws_subnets" "default" {         
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}

variable "server_port" {              
  description = "The port the server will use for HTTP requests"
  type        = number
  default     = 80
}

resource "aws_security_group" "alb" {  
  name = "terraform-example-alb"

  ingress {
    from_port     = 80
    to_port       = 80
    protocol      = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks   = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port     = 0
    to_port       = 0
    protocol      = "-1"
    cidr_blocks   = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "asg" {   
  name    = "terraform-asg-example"
  port    = var.server_port
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id  = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  health_check {                        
    path       = "/"
    protocol    = "HTTP"
    matcher     = "200"
    interval    = 15
    timeout     = 3
    healthy_threshold = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "example" {            
  name                = "terraform-asg-example"      
  load_balancer_type  = "application"                 
  subnets             = data.aws_subnets.default.*.id   
  security_groups     = [aws_security_group.alb.id]    
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {       
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.example.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  
  default_action {
    type = "fixed-response"

    fixed_response {
      content_type = "text/plain"
      message_body = "404: page not found"
      status_code  = 404
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "asg" {    
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.http.arn
  priority    = 100

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["*"]
    }
  }

  action {
    type      = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.asg.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example" {         
  image_id      = "ami-04a7c24c015ef1e4c"              
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  security_groups = [aws_security_group.instance.id]    

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p ${var.server_port} &
              EOF

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {                      
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.example.name    
  vpc_zone_identifier = data.aws_subnets.default.*.id            

  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.asg.arn]             
  health_check_type = "ELB"

  min_size = 2
  max_size = 3

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "terraform-asg-example"
    propagate_at_launch = true  
  }
}

output "alb_dns_name" {                       
  value       = aws_lb.example.dns_name
  description = "The domain name of the load balancer"
}
```

I tried to delete that part, or change some other variables but got more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `filter` as explained in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnets):

```
data "aws_subnets" "default" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.default.id]
  }
}
```